# Eclipse v4.7.1a: ant build broken: Launch configuration <build.file> references non-existing project <container project>

Tags: eclipse, ant

It seems that since eclipse `v4.7.1a` (fresh install), it is no more possible to execute any `ant` build. 
Each time it fails with the following message:

```
Launch configuration <name of build file> references non-existing project <name of the containing project>
```

We have tested it with many different configuration (eclipse-jee, eclipse-rcp ...), each time with a fresh eclipse `v4.7.1a` install.
After further investigation, this occurs only if the `build.xml` file in not under a "java" kind of project, which is the case for all of our workspaces (30+...).
Everything worked well with `v4.7.0`
In the `.log`file we can see:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking
  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.configureBlocking(Native Method)
  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.launchConfigurations.RemoteAntBuildListener$ServerConnection.run(RemoteAntBuildListener.java:89)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.launching 4 107 2017-10-22 21:19:26.676
!MESSAGE Launch configuration org.titou10.jtb.build build.xml references non-existing project org.titou10.jtb.build.
```

**[UPDATE]**
If the `build.xml` file is inside a Java project. Everyhting works fine as before
If the `build.xml` file is in a regular project or a EAR project (our case) it does not work...
It seems there is a way to make it work in those cases:

1. right click on build.xml
2. `Run As`->`Ant Build...`-> Select the "`JRE`" tab,
3. check "`Run in the same JRE as the workspace` "...

and it works as before...

It is clearly a regression from previous version...

Comment: Does this fresh installation have the permission to listen to incoming connections, so that it can debug properly?

Comment: Has this been filed as a bug with Eclipse?

Comment: @marc82ch: Done : [#526539](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526539)

Comment: Thank you for reporting the error to Eclipse. You have already answered your question yourself. But for all those who read your question, I have added an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you're right, it's an Eclipse bug:

[**Eclipse bug 522581 - *Cannot run ant build file from generic project***](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=522581)

The bug was introduced in Oxygen.0 (4.7.0), probably by an update of the built-in Ant framework. A **fix** for this bug is **scheduled for Oxygen.2 (4.7.2), December 20, 2017**.

As already described by yourself in the question, ***Run in the same JRE as the workspace*** can be used **as a workaround**.

Comment: That workaround is great until you actually need to use a different JRE...

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error after copying an existing Eclipse project to a new machine. In this case the JRE no longer existed (it had a different path on the previous computer).

I was a little confused by the answers above (but probably my fault because I didn't read the update to the question properly, and didn't see that it contained an answer).

I was able to use both the same JRE as the workspace OR simply just choose another JRE.

To get there, in the Eclipse project explorer right click on the `build.xml` file, then choose `Ant Build...` (make sure it's the one with the ellipsis)

I was able to use both the same JRE as the workspace like this

[image: Same JRE as workspace]

... or just choose another JRE, as you can see here.

[image: With another JRE]