# How to get full command from Eclipse external tool configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

So I've been hit [by an Eclipse bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46990633/546060). \o/

Long story short, either I've got to install an old Eclipse and set up a bunch of workspaces from scratch (a laborious process that'll take half a day at least) or I can run a few specific ant commands manually. However I can't seem to find a way to extract the full command from a specific external tool configuration.

Any ideas? Or will I have to build the commands manually (a few properties, a custom ANT_HOME and alternative JRE make them a bit lengthy).

Comment: Is it an option to try 4.7.2RC1 until 4.7.2 is released?

Comment: I will try the separate download as I seem to be up to date according to the update site; the fix may not have made it into rc1 I fear. Maybe rc2 will fix it in 2 days?

Comment: So I had another brain spark and TIL you can revert updates in Eclipse so reverted to 4.7.0 and it all works again.

Comment: Good to know! For sure the best option in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really the direct answer, but the best solution to my problem...

You can revert updates in Eclipse. In my case the bug was introduced by 4.7.1 and I had originally installed 4.7.0 so I simply reverted those updates and it restored the feature I relied upon (running ant in an alternative JRE).